# Avoid repeating key name when initializing hash to local variable?

Tags: ruby

Consider this ruby code:

```
red = '#f00'
green = '#0f0'
colors = {red: red, green: green}
```

The repetition in the final line is unsightly.

In ES6 javascript, there is a nice shortcut:

```
const red = '#f00'
const green = '#0f0'
const colors = {red, green} // creates {red: '#f00', green: '#0f0'}
```

Is there a way to achieve the something similar in ruby?

Comment: Short answer is no. There's nothing built-in that behaves like this, and to the best of my knowledge, you can't overload the `{}` for hash construction.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such syntax in Ruby.

However, you *could* do something like:

```
red = '#f00'
green = '#0f0'
colors = Hash[[:red, :green].map { |v| [v, eval(v.to_s)] }]
```

Is this really better? Probably not in the case of just two keys, but it probably is in the case of dozens of keys.

Note that this uses `eval()` to get the variable value – only run it on trusted data! If they're instance variables you can use the (safe) `instance_variable_get`:

```
@red = '#f00'
@green = '#0f0'
colors = Hash[[:red, :green].map { |v| [v, instance_variable_get("@#{v}")] }]
```